# Hide a div onclick in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to know how to hide a `div` `onclick` in **pure javascript** without using something like `getElementById`.

The goal for this is to scale and work if the number of `divs` is unknown.

Here is the current pattern that only hides the 1st `div`:

```
document.getElementById('msg0').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    document.getElementById('msg0').style.display = 'none';
});
```

And here are the sample `divs`:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" id="msg0">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close">
    &times;
    </button>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
    Three credits remain in your account.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="msg1">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close">
    &times;
    </button>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
    Profile details updated.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-warning" id="msg2">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close">
    &times;
    </button>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
    Your account expires in three days.
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger" id="msg3">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close">
    &times;
    </button>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
    Document deleted.
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `document.getElementById`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event delegation. Only one click handler is set and works with alerts dynamically added.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var alertElement = findUpTag(event.target, '.alert');

    if (alertElement) {
       alertElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
});

function findUpTag(el, selector) {
    if (el.matches(selector)) {
        return el;
    }

    while (el.parentNode) {
        el = el.parentNode;
        if (el.matches && el.matches(selector)) {
            return el;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ht2qp6zj/3/**

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add one common class for all the div elements that need to implement this same functionality. For example lets name that class 'hideable':

```
/// Html
<div class='hideable'></div>

// Javascript
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hideable');

for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
{
    var element = elements[i];
    element.addEventListener('click', onClick);
}

function onClick(event){
    event.target.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: It seems they already have a common class of *alert*. `document.querySelectorAll('.alert')` is more widely supported than `document.getElementsByClassName('alert')`. Also, the *onClick* function can simply be `this.style.display = 'none'`.

Comment: I think he only want the div that was clicked on to be hidden, not all the divs that share the same class to be hidden all at once at the click of one div.

Comment: @RobG querySelectorAll has partial support in IE 8 while getElementsByClassName does not have any support in IE 8. That is the only difference. 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector
http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname

Comment: just to add that `querySelectorAll` will return a non-live node list of elements.

Comment: @frosty You are right that is the behavior that he wants, and that is exactly the behavior that this code achieves.

Answer (score -3):

Something like this would suffice. This will hide only the div that is clicked on. I will explain how this works if you make a request.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>

<div>
    one
</div> 
<div>
    two
</div>
```

Comment: The question was for plain Javascript, not jquery.

Comment: I believe the OP requested pure JavaScript, no Jquery.

Comment: I understand that.. however the OP asked for "pure JavaScript" meaning he either isn't interested, or is already aware of how to do this in Jquery.

Comment: @CarsonClark It's possible that he meant that, but we can't be sure without his clarification. Let's ask the OP instead, instead of arguing back and forth between us two.

Comment: I think the accepted definition of "pure javascript" is javascript that does not use a framework like jQuery. For example, if you look on jsFiddle and expand the library dropdown, you will see an item with value "No-Library (pure JS)"

Comment: @BenGuest Ah. My mistake then.